# Upload Image in comment of github issue/pull request?

Tags: github, github-api

Is it possible to upload an image as a comment to a github pull request/issue via the API?

My use case: I have a selenium test suite that takes images that are helpful in code reviews.

Comment: Just drag and drop I think

Comment: it's important that I can upload the images programmatically from a server and automatically attach them to code reviews to avoid burdening developers on the project (i.e. I'm looking for an automated solution :)

Comment: we already have jenkins commenting on PRs indicating the build status, so it seems reasonable that something should also be able to upload images

Comment: Can you host the image somewhere and just link it with markdown on the body of the comment?